# Can you get the name of a resx string accessed through dot notation using some sort of reflection?

Tags: .net, vb.net, resx

I have language resource files that I typically access using dot notation like so:

MyStrings.This_is_a_test_string

However, I now need to get two language versions of the same string in error handling. The reason is the local string is shown to the user while the English string is written to the log file.

I can call the function below using a statement such as:

----- begin code -----

```
strCustomErrorMsg = GetCustomErrorMsgStrings(MyStrings.ResourceManager.BaseName, "This_is_a_test_string")



Public Function GetCustomErrorMsgStrings(strResource As String, strProperty As String) As String
    Dim rm As ResourceManager
    Dim strLocal As String
    Dim strEnglish As String
    Dim strCustomErrorMsg As String

    rm = New ResourceManager(strResource, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())

    strLocal = rm.GetString(strProperty, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture)

    SetLanguage("en")

    strEnglish = rm.GetString(strProperty, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture)

    SetLanguage(g_strLanguage)

    strCustomErrorMsg = "Local Text: " & strLocal & "||||" & vbNewLine & "English: " & strEnglish

    GetCustomErrorMsgStrings = strCustomErrorMsg

End Function
```

----- endcode -----

The problem is I want to continue to use the strongly typed resx class and dot notation such as MyStrings.This_is_a_test_string so Visual Studio catches non existent resource strings in real-time.

For the strProperty parameter, is there any way I can do something like passing MyStrings.This_is_a_test_string.GetName.ToString() which will reflect the name "This_is_a_test_string" back to me?

My concern is I will make typos when entering the literal strings such as "This_is_a_test_string" for the strProperty parameter and maintenance will become more difficult.

Thanks for the help.

Matthew

Comment: Your best bet might be something based on the expression machinery.  See http://www.jagregory.com/writings/introduction-to-static-reflection for some discussion on doing this in C#.  In VB, the thing that you have to watch out for is that the VB compiler will sometimes wrap your property access in a unary conversion to `Object` (so instead of your expression `Body` being a `MemberExpression`, instead it's a `UnaryExpression` and its `Operand` is the `MemberExpression` you're trying to get.

Comment: HI Craig. Static reflection looks exactly like what I need. However, when I call the sample function in the article you provided I get this error:

Dim PropInfo As PropertyInfo = GetProperty(DevStrings.This_is_a_test_string)

BC36645: Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in method 'Public Function GetProperty(Of TEntity)(ByVal expression As Expression(Of Func(Of TEntity, Object))) As PropertyInfo' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

Any ideas on how to get this to be working code?

Comment: I don't have any uses where the containing type is inferred, so I don't know that it's possible.  I think property type inference could work depending on how you set the whole thing up.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is that you will make typos when entering the literal string then just use `NameOf(MyStrings.This_is_a_test_string)`.